# Asynchronous function returns Promise{pending} instead of a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-secret-manager

I need the function `getAUTH` to return a value that i'll later assign to variable 'AUTH' but it returns Promise {pending}.
This is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const { getinfobipAuth } = require('../secrets-manager')

//get infobipAUTH from secret manager
const getAUTH = async () => await getinfobipAuth()
const AUTH = getAUTH()
console.log(AUTH)

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH
```

Tried resolving the promise like:
`const AUTH = getAUTH().then(res => res)`
But assigning the value AUTH still doesn't return a value.
Can a variable declared outside a function be assigned a value from a promise?

I'll appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Async functions always return Promises; you can't get a value *synchronously* which is retrieved *asynchronously*. The only way is to have the caller call `.then` on the Promise, or for the caller to `await` the Promise to unwrap it

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance I have called `.then` on the caller of `getAUTH() ` as this 
`const AUTH = getAUTH().then(res => {
  return res
})
console.log(AUTH)`

 but I still have the log as `Promise{<pending>}`